# Green function and Fourier transformation and inverse transformation

Tags: conventions, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, greens-functions

Let $G(x, y_1, \cdots, y_n)$ be my Green function

I want to expand Green function with Fouier transformation of $y_{i}$ and inverse Foruier on $x$ so that $$G(x, y_1,\cdots, y_n) = \int dk_{x} \int_{k_1, \cdots, k_n} G'(k_{x}, k_{1}, \cdots, k_n) e^{-i k_x \cdot x} \delta(k_x + \sum_{i} k_{i}) e^{ik_{1} \cdot y_{1}} \cdots e^{i k_{n} \cdot y_{n}}. $$

Is this correct expressions?

Using $\delta(x-y) = \int dk e^{ik(x-y)}$, I obtained
\begin{align}
e^{-i k_x \cdot x} \delta(k_x + \sum_i k_i) e^{ik_1 \cdot y_1} \cdots e^{i k_n \cdot y_n} & = \int_{z}dz e^{iz(k_x + \sum_i k_i)}e^{-i k_x \cdot x}e^{ik_1 \cdot y_1} \cdots e^{i y_n \cdot k_n} \\
&  = \int_{z} dz e^{i k_{x} (z-x)} e^{i \sum_{i} k_i(z+y_i)}
\end{align}

and this reproduce the delta function on $x,y_i$ and so on.

From the sign of $x$ and $y$, I am confused whether my momentum conservation is $ \delta(k_x + \sum_{i} k_{i})$ or $ \delta(k_x - \sum_{i} k_{i})$. It seems the second one is more appropriate but I can not confidence about this. Which one is correct one and can you explain me why?

Comment: What about factors of $2\pi$?

Comment: @Qmechanic, Here I just don't consider $(2\pi)$ factors for simplicilty.